# sharing data between mobile apps using the same SDK

Tags: android, ios

If I have a mobile SDK that is included in 2 different applications on a mobile phone, and I would like to read from and write to a shared database owned by that SDK (no one else has access), how would I do that?  Interested in solutions for both Android & iOS.  The 2 applications are not owned by me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried [Content Providers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to do that on device on iOS unless you develop both apps using the same developer ID.

I think you'd have to set up a server database and have both apps connect to it via cellular or WiFi.